# Postgres text column that only allows/converts to lowercase and no special characters such as: Ñöáè

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-9.2, postgresql-9.4

I have a table and I want that 1 column to only accept lowercase strings and with no special characters such as Ñóáöäë, etc...

Is there anyway to add this constrain to the column?

```
CREATE TABLE lawyer (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR NOT NULL,
  url_name VARCHAR NOT NULL,
  gender VARCHAR(1) check (gender in ('m','f')) NOT NULL
);
```

The column I want to add the constrain is url_name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the desired characters in the second parameter of this `translate()` call:

```
CREATE TABLE lawyer (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR NOT NULL,
  url_name VARCHAR check(translate(url_name, 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', '') = '') NOT NULL,
  gender VARCHAR(1) check (gender in ('m','f')) NOT NULL
);

insert into lawyer
values (default, 'Adam Smith', 'domain', 'f');

INSERT 0 1

insert into lawyer
values (default, 'Adam Smith', 'dömain', 'f');

ERROR:  new row for relation "lawyer" violates check constraint "lawyer_url_name_check"
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (3, Adam Smith, dömain, f).
```

---

Alternatively you can create a trigger, which modifies the value on the fly:

```
create or replace function lawyer_before_insert_or_update()
returns trigger language plpgsql as $$
begin
    new.url_name := lower(new.url_name);
    if translate(new.url_name, 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', '') <> '' then
        raise exception 'Incorrect url name.';
    end if;
    return new;
end $$;

create trigger lawyer_before_insert_or_update
before insert or update on lawyer
for each row execute procedure lawyer_before_insert_or_update();

insert into lawyer
values (default, 'Adam Smith', 'DOMAIN', 'f')
returning *;

 id |    name    | url_name | gender 
----+------------+----------+--------
  4 | Adam Smith | domain   | f
(1 row)

INSERT 0 1

insert into lawyer
values (default, 'Adam Smith', 'dömain', 'f');

ERROR:  Incorrect url name.
```

Comment: thanks a lot is there a constrain or way to make url_name lower case?

Comment: The constraint can only check (and reject wrong) values. You need a trigger to change the value on input. See the edited answer.

Answer (score 3):

For transforms (such as converting to lower case) I agree with triggers.  For allowed characters, however, I would suggest using a domain if this is a recurring requirement.

Something like:

```
 create domain lower_ascii AS text check VALUE ~ '^[a-z]*$';
```

Domains have a couple advantages including the fact that they provide a single point of management across all uses and you can modify the check constraint globally if requirements change.