# How to restrict varchar in postgres to allow only specific characters in DB?

Tags: sql, django, regex, postgresql

I have a case where I need to allow only specific characters in a varchar column in Postgres DB using django.

It should restrict the user from entering other characters even if he directly edit using raw SQL queries.
Are there any validators that I can use with both Django and Postgres.

I found this helpful for using in Django - [How can I make a Django form field contain only alphanumeric characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17165147/how-can-i-make-a-django-form-field-contain-only-alphanumeric-characters)
But what if the user modifies the data using raw SQL queries?

Comment: i think you can find your answer here: [link] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37847618/postgres-text-column-that-only-allows-converts-to-lowercase-and-no-special-chara

Answer (score 3):

In PostreSQL you can add a [`CHECK`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-CHECK-CONSTRAINTS) constraint to a specific column, e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE gender (val text);
```

This constraint will only allow the values `f` and `m` int field `val`

```
ALTER TABLE gender ADD CONSTRAINT gender_vals CHECK (val IN ('f','m'));
```

Testing

```
INSERT INTO gender VALUES ('f'),('m');
INSERT 0 2

INSERT INTO gender VALUES ('x');
ERROR:  new row for relation "gender" violates check constraint "gender_vals"
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (x).
```

Alternatively you can already create the table with this constraint, which is described in the documentation linked above.

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/gJQPGVrC)